# Polar decomposition of the Volterra integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, matrix-decomposition

*Now asked on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355554/polar-decomposition-of-the-volterra-integral-operator), too.*

> Define the Volterra integral operator (or numerical differentiation operator)
>   $$
> T: L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1]), \ 
> f(x) \mapsto \int_{0}^{x} f(y) dy.
> $$
>   Find its polar decomposition $T = U_T | T |$.

First I tried to find $|T| := (T^* T)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
We have
$$
T^*: L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1]), \ 
f(x) \mapsto \int_{x}^{1} f(y) dy.
$$
and therefore
$$
T^* T: L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1]), \ 
f(x) \mapsto \int_{x}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(z) dz dy.
$$
Now I got stuck when finding $\sqrt{T^* T}$. I found out that $T^2 \ne T^* T$ and $(T^*)^2 \ne T^* T$.
Can somebody please give me a hint?

I have also tried writing out $T^* T$ more explicitly: denote by $F$ the anti-derivative of $f$ and by $\mathscr{F}$ the antiderivative of $F$.
The we have
$$
(T^* T f)(x)
= \int_{x}^{1} F(y) - F(0) dy
= \int_{x}^{1} F(y) dy - (1 - x) F(0)
= \mathscr{F}(1) - \mathscr{F}(x) - (1 - x)F(0).
$$

**Edit.**
I also know that
$$
(T^{n + 1} f)
= \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^x (x - y)^n f(y) dy.
$$
Maybe this can help use find a closed form for $(I - T^* T)^n$?

**Edit 2.**
I know that
$$
| T |
= \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \sigma_n \langle \cdot, v_n \rangle v_n,
$$
where $\sigma_n := \frac{1}{\pi\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)}$ are the singular values of $T^* T$ and $(v_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset L^2([0,1])$ a orthonormal basis of $\overline{\text{ran}(T)}$ which fulfils
$$
T^* T x
= \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \sigma_n^2 \langle x, v_n \rangle, v_n.
$$
The eigenfunctions of $T^* T$ are $f_n(x) = C \cdot \cos(\sigma_n^{-1} x)$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Regarding the sequence $(a_n)$ in Matematleta's answer: 
The first $a_{2n}$ are $$\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{5}{128}, \frac{7}{256}, \frac{21}{1024}, \frac{33}{2048}, \frac{429}{32768}\right),$$ the odd terms are zero.
The numerators, omitting the zeros, are [A098597](https://oeis.org/A098597) on OEIS and the denominators (omitting zeros again) are given by $2^{\ell}$, $\ell \in \{1,3,4,7,8,10,11,15\}$, which is [this](https://oeis.org/A184823) in OEIS.

*The reason I hope there exists an explicit answer is that this exercise is taken from this problem set from LMU Munich wherein it states "Important: the full solution here is to produce the explicit "closed" form of the operators $U_T$ and $|T|$. Giving the canonical decomposition of $|T|$
is not enough, show that in fact $|T|$
is an integral operator and $U_T$ is a unitary operator (with an explicit, "easy" form)."*

Comment: Do you know that $T^* T$ compact self-adjoint and so is diagonalizable and its operator norm is the magnitude of its largest eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1):

How about this sketch:

Notice that $f:x\mapsto 1-(1-x)^{1/2}$ has a power series expansion defined by $1-(1-x)^{1/2}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_nx^n$ which converges for $|x|<1.$ It is easy to show by letting $x\to 1^-$ that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n=1$. We will apply this below.

First, normalize $T^*T$ so its norm is $1$. Then define $S:=I-\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n(I-T^*T)^n$. Since $\|I-T^*T\|\le1,\ S$ is norm convergent. Now check that $S\ge 0$, is self-adjoint, and satisfies $S^2=T^*T.$ This gives a formula for $|T|$.

Now, since $\||T|f\|^2=\|Tf\|^2$ it follows that $T$ and $|T|$ have the same nullspace. And $U(|T|f):=Tf$ is an isometry mapping the range of $|T|$ onto the range of $T.$ Now set $Uf:=0$ for all $f\in \text{Ran}|T|^{\perp}$ (OK since $\text{Ran}\ |T|^{\perp} = \text{Ker}\ |T|$ ), and check that $T=U|T|.$

Comment: Yes, I forgot to raise to the power $n.$ As for your other comment, the point is not that $|1-x|<1$, rather that the $norm$ is: since $\|T^*T\|=1,\  \|I-T^*T\|\le 1$ and since $\sum a_n=1,$ the series converges.

Comment: The reason I hope there exists an explicit answer is that this exercise is taken from [this problem set from LMU Munich](http://www.math.lmu.de/~michel/WS11-12_FA2_Assignment09.pdf) wherein it states "Important: the full solution here is to produce the explicit "closed" form of the operators
$U_T$ and $|T|$. Giving the canonical decomposition of $|V|$ is not enough, show that in fact $|T|$ is an integral operator and $U_T$ is a unitary operator (with an explicit, "easy" form)." Can you make any sense of what I have quoted above?